# Getting views in Fragment from a super Activity

Tags: android, textview, fragment

I have activity A which extends activity B. Activity A sets a Fragment that has a TextView. I want to change some aspects of that view programmatically via activity B. In the activity I have:

```
public void changeFragmentText() {
    FragmentA frag = (FragmentA) 
           getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
    if(frag instanceof FragmentA) {
        frag.getImageText().setText("Change to something");
        frag.getImageText().setTextColor(color.DarkGray);
        frag.getImageText().setClickable(false);
    }
}
```

Where `getImageText()` get the TextView from the fragment. However, this has no effect on the text. Is this advisable to use in changing text in a fragment from an activity?

Comment: You are thinking backwards. If Activity A extends Activity B then Activity B has no concept of what Activity A actually is or does. You have to build the functionality into the super class and then use that in the extended class not the other way around.